# IE11 issue with Embedded PDF

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML page that loads an embedded pdf on the page dynamically via an ajax call.

The below iframe code is pasted onto the Html page from the ajax method

```
<iframe src="${pdfpath}" width="1000" height="500">
```

It works well the first time it is called, however in subsequent calls there is an issue. The PDF loads fine, its the other contents on the page that disappears. This issue only happens in IE11, works fine in Chrome, Firefox and even IE9.

One thing odd I noticed is, when I open up the F12 developer tools, the remaining contents of the page appears again. Keep in mind that these contents have already been loaded the first time the page was loaded, the ajax method just inserts the iframe element onto the html page.

Below is a sample of how the ajax method inserts the data

```
$("#pdfDiv").empty().html(data);
```

Any help is appreciated on how to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing the iframe element with an object element

```
<object data="${pdfpath}" type="application/pdf">
       <embed src="${pdfpath}" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since internet explorer 11 came up, everyone seems to have troubles when wanting to display or download pdf files, and me too. Personnaly, i just stopped using pdf. But, here is something for you, i don't know if it will help :

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/internet-explorer-11-windows-7-pdf-files-will-not/3882b9cb-05ff-45de-acc6-0f6b8b752ed6?auth=1